# Does Angular $http Service Call into the $exceptionHandler on Http Error Responses

Tags: angularjs

I was under the impression that http errors returned from requests inside of the angular $http service would be passed through the $exceptionHandler, but I am seeing some behavior that makes me think otherwise.

Can anyone confirm whether $http service should be passing a message to $exceptionHandler in the case of a 500 http status response code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, no they don't pass through the exception handler.  The angular documentation states:

> Any uncaught exception in angular expressions is delegated to this
>   service. The default implementation simply delegates to $log.error
>   which logs it into the browser console.

A 500 error wouldn't be considered an uncaught exception. We use the $httpProvider to intercept the responses and deal with 500 codes on their own.  We made a service to handle this functionality.

Our app config looks like this:

```
appModule.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$provide',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $provide) {
    // Http interceptor to handle session timeouts and basic errors
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(['httpHandlersSrv', function (httpHandlersSrv) {
        return function (promise) { return promise.then(httpHandlersSrv.success, httpHandlersSrv.error); };
    }]);
    routeProvider = $routeProvider;
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
]);
```

This is what our $httpHandlersSrv looks like where we handle the 500 code errors:

```
angular.module('appModule').factory('httpHandlersSrv', ['$q', '$location', '$rootScope', 'toaster', '$window', function ($q, $location, $rootScope, toaster, $window) {
return {
    success: function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    error: function (response) {
        switch (response.status) {
            case 0:
                //Do something when we don't get a response back
                break;
            case 401:
                //Do something when we get an authorization error
                break;
            case 400:
               //Do something for other errors
                break;
            case 500:
               //Do something when we get a server error
                break;
            default:
                //Do something with other error codes
                break;
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that 500 errors wouldn't be considered exceptions. This was the key for my issue.